# Get value from class

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, select

So i have a class `Take` for connecting to *mysql*. In that class I have a method to call a query to take the last record from mysql table.

```
    public void Balance()
    {
        string query = "SELECT balance FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }          
    }
```

In the main form I'm calling that class and that method

```
    take.Balance();
```

I know, that from code above, i don't get any value but `NULL`, so i am asking how i can take value from that query and put it in the `TextBox` in the main form?

Comment: Your function `Balance()` returns a `void` (as in 'no return-value'). Change this for example to string, read the data from your query (which you have to change, `ExecuteNonQuery` does not return values) and then return it with `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have look:

```
// You probably want to return value: decimal, not void
public decimal Balance() {
  // Make sql readable
  string query = 
    @"SELECT balance 
        FROM history 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
       LIMIT 1 ";

  // do not cache connection, but create a new one instead 
  using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringHere)) {
    conn.Open();

    // wrap IDisposable into using  
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn)) {
      // you want to return values: ExecuteReader (or ExecuteScalar) 
      // instead of ExecuteNonQuery
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.Read())
          return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(0));
        else
          return 0m; // cursor is empty, let's return 0   
      }
    }          
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But now i want to get that value in my main form i am typing `take.Balance();`  but it shows Warning 1 Field 'Budget.Form1.take' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null. What should i do in my main Form to put that value in the textbox?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think you should improve your basic knowledge of programming. There are two big problems in your example code:

1. You want to get the value, but your function is void, not return anything even set the value to some variable
2. ExecuteNonQuery is not your case.

**For example:**

```
 public string Balance()
    {
        string query = "SELECT balance FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider. First, the query

```
"SELECT balance FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

is a query in the sense that some useful data from the database should be returned, it should not be executed with a the method `ExecuteNonQuery`, which is intended to return the number of rows affected by a non-query statement. Second, the return type of `Balance` would have to be changed to some other type than `void`, say `int` or something similar, which would have to be returned to the caller.